# How to get data in json form

Tags: php, json, database, api

Currently, I am making an API and I want the data in `JSON` format. But I am not able to get it. It is coming in normal form. But how to convert it into `JSON`. If I am writing `json_encode($response)` outside the loop then I am getting the data in json format but only one data.

If i wriing the json encode inside the loop then i am getting all the data but not in `JSON` form. How to solve this. I am not able to get the perfect solution for ths question.

```
$tsym = strtolower($_REQUEST['tsym']);
$time = strtolower($_REQUEST['time']);
$mil = $time;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
$normal_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `forex` where pair='".$tsym."' and date >=  '".$normal_date."' order by date limit 0,10";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$response = array();


while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $from_sym = $rows['pair'];

 //if(!isset($response[$from_sym]))
      {
           $response[$from_sym] = $rows;
          //echo json_encode($response, true);
     //}
      print_r( json_encode($response)); //this prints all the data but not 
        in json form

       }
      print_r( json_encode($response)); //this prints single data but in 
      json form
```

I want all the data but in json form. how to get it? Thank you for the help.
I want data like this:

```
{
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "33",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-22 20:42:21",
        "price": "110.413",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
},
{
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "75",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-22 20:42:29",
        "price": "110.413",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
},
{
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "117",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-23 11:25:47",
        "price": "110.585",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
},
{
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "159",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-23 12:34:54",
        "price": "110.816",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
},
{
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "201",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-23 12:35:04",
        "price": "110.825",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
}
```

But i am getting only one data.

Comment: the code seems correct  what your problem ?? what is the contt for $rows['pair']?

Comment: 'pair' is a field in database. so the value in this particular field will be printed.

Comment: {
        "CHFJPY": {
            "id": "33",
            "pair": "CHFJPY",
            "date": "2018-04-22 20:42:21",
            "price": "110.413",
            "change_rate": "0",
            "fetched": "1"
        }
    },

Comment: CHFJPY this is the value of pair. which has been taken from database and printed accordingly.

Comment: how many rows  you have  ?

Comment: 5 rows @scaisEdge

Comment: JSON is text, that's one of the points of it. So that part of your question already doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append your row to the final array `$response` in your while loop

```
$response = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $from_sym = $rows['pair'];
    $res[$from_sym] = $rows;
    $response[] = $res;
}
print_r(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Yea got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

is not clear why you have not  json  so  .. in more clear way try

```
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $response[$rows['pair']] = $rows;
  }
  $myJSON  =    json_encode($response);
  var_dump($myJSON);
```

this should buil a $reponse array with the related  vleus  for each 'pair' index

but could be you need  all the rows result  so try

```
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $response[] = $rows;
  }
  $mySecondJSON  =    json_encode($response);
  var_dump($mySecondJSON);
```

or

```
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $response[] = $rows['pair'];
  }
  $myOtherJSON  =    json_encode($response);
  var_dump($myOtherJSON);
```

Comment: what  do you have using my code  ??  ., i have just refactored  your code  ,,, in  a synthetic  way ..

Comment: If i do this then i am getting only one data as a response. But in total there should be 5 data

Comment: string(118) "{"CHFJPY":{"id":"201","pair":"CHFJPY","date":"2018-04-23 12:35:04","price":"110.825","change_rate":"0","fetched":"1"}}" this is what i get from your code

Comment: this is a json string  where for the index  CHFJPY you have the rows   content as in your code ..

Comment: how many different values you have for 'pair' ..?  .. you have only  CHFJPY?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `json_encode` into the outside of `while` loop

```
<?php
$tsym_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['tsym']);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_REQUEST['time']/1000);
$sql = sprintf(
        "SELECT * FROM `forex` WHERE `pain`='%s' AND `date`>='%s' ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 0,10",
        $tsym_escaped,
        $date
    );
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $response[$row['pair']] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Also, the way you're passing the data into the SQL query is insecure and can lead into a SQL injection.

Comment: i did that but in that case i get only one data.

Comment: {
    "CHFJPY": {
        "id": "33",
        "pair": "CHFJPY",
        "date": "2018-04-22 20:42:21",
        "price": "110.413",
        "change_rate": "0",
        "fetched": "1"
    }
},